# serving files on the server with express.js for angular8 ssr

Tags: angular, express, server-side, angular-universal

I'm using A8 ssr or angular universal, with express.js, however I don't know if this is the correct setup to server all the files, on my server.ts I have this:

```
app.use(express.static('public-optimized'));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('files'));
app.use(express.static('/my-project/*.*'));
app.use(express.static('*.js'));
app.use(express.static('*.json'));
app.use(express.static('*.css'));
app.use(express.static('*.png'));
app.use(express.static('*.jpg'));
app.use(express.static('/assets/*.*'));

app.use(express.static('/main.js'));
app.use(express.static('/styles.css'));
app.use(express.static('/runtime.js'));
app.use(express.static('/polyfills.js'));
app.use(express.static('/vendor.js'));
app.use(express.static('/scripts.js'));
```

Is this the correct setup?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like correct setup. It's not appropriated to set static files.

According to https://angular.io/guide/universal, You can setup like

```
// Server static files from your angular build folder
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));
```

Where DIST_FOLDER = your build folder path(Generally it will be path of `dist/` folder) & `'browser' is the name of your inner folder` within dist/ folder as you are doing SSR